# There is no callback like onAutoFocused() from api 21 and above

Tags: android, camera2

how to capture a photo automatically at focus in android using camera2 api ? There is no callback like onAutoFocused() from api 21 and above.

Comment: please provide some code to clarify

Answer (score 1):

You have to trigger AF and AE manually. 
The standard pipeline is:

1. set `CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER` to `CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START` in the `CaptureRequest.Builder` that you use for preview and submit to the session through `CameraCaptureSession capture` method. After you have called capture remember to reset `CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER` to `CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_IDLE` in the CaptureRequest.Builder for preview;
2. Wait for AF to finish checking if `CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE of TotalCaptureResult` in the preview callback is `CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED || CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED || CONTROL_AF_STATE_PASSIVE_FOCUSED || CONTROL_AF_STATE_PASSIVE_UNFOCUSED`
3. When AF is finished trigger AE setting `CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER` to `CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_START` in the `CaptureRequest.Builder` that you use for preview and submit to the session through `CameraCaptureSession capture` method. After you have called capture remember to reset `CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER` to `CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_IDLE` in the CaptureRequest.Builder for preview;
4. Wait for AE to finish checking if `CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE of TotalCaptureResult` in the preview callback is `CONTROL_AE_STATE_CONVERGED || CONTROL_AE_STATE_FLASH_REQUIRED || CONTROL_AE_STATE_LOCKED`
5. Now you can take the picture, focused and well exposed

I have experienced also that is possible to trigger AF e AE at the same time   (steps 1-3) and wait for them simultaneously (steps 2-4).